# Docker Image not uploading to ecr from jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I created a CI/CD pipline which builds a docker image and pushes to docker image to amazon ecr.

The docker image build perfectly but does not upload to ecr

After building the image it keeps retrying to upload the image to ecr but exits after several trials

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        registryCredential = 'ecr:us-east-1:aws-cred'
        appRegistry = "xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myappimg"
        vprofileRegistry = "https://xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        dockerImage = ''
        
    }
    stages{
        stage('Fetch code') {
          steps{
             git branch: 'docker', url: 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx.git'
          }  
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'
            }
        }
        stage('Test'){
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }

        }

       
    stage('Build App Image') {
       steps {
       
         script {
                dockerImage = docker.build( appRegistry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER", "./Docker-files/app/multistage/")
             }

     }
    
    }

    stage('Upload App Image') {
          steps{
            script {
              docker.withRegistry( vprofileRegistry, registryCredential ) {
                dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
                dockerImage.push('latest')
              }
            }
          }
     }
         
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a connectivity issue. Where is the Jenkins host running?

Comment: It is running in a linode servers @Paolo

Comment: @etranz Have you created the mentioned repository?